# sudo command is asking for password inspite of changing sudoers file

Tags: sudo

I have been trying to run a simple command using sudo, but everytime i run the command i am getting a password prompt. I am root user of that system. Here is the command i am running to invoke sudo

```
sudo -E -u  nonrootusername /opt/xyz/bin/run_cmd -stop
```

and here is my entry in sudoers file

```
%ynonrootuasername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/xyz/bin/run_cmd -stop
```

Is invoking sudo -u the root cause of my troubles?

Comment: `%ynonrootuasername` defines rights for groups, not for users.

Comment: But in Linux when u create a user, a group also gets created of the same name to which the user is added, isn't it?...pls correct me if I am wrong

Comment: sudoers defines rights for the user calling sudo

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a syntax error :

% Is used for groups, you have wrote **%ynonrootusername** so you should be part of **ynonrootusername** group.

Also if you want to allow only nonrootusername just put :

```
nonrootuasername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/xyz/bin/run_cmd -stop
```

Maybe you have mispelled %y characters **&y**nonrootusername

Comment: Actually even when I tried

Comment: Actually even after trying this

Comment: put the content of /etc/sudoers line & execute "id ynonrootusername"